# How to assign PHP array values as comma seperated string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two mysql table, sla and department, I am creating SLA and while creating sla, there is selection of multiple departments,

When user submit SLA form, respected departments in department table get sla id,

But after adding i need to pull that added SLA with join of departments which are updated,

Below is my code for controller,

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
    $result = $this->model_admin->updatesla($sla_data); // Add SLA
    if (!$result) {
        $lastentry = $this->model_admin->LastEntrysla(); //Get last added SLA
        foreach($this->input->post('sla_department') as $department_id) {
            $sladepartment_data = array( 'sla_id' => $lastentry->sla_id);
            $this->model_admin->updatedepartmentsla($department_id,$sladepartment_data);//Update SLA to respective multiselected department
        }
        //Now getadded SLA with join of department
        foreach($this->model_admin->getaddedsla($lastentry->sla_id) as $returnsla) {
            $returnslajson = array(  'sla_id' => $returnsla->sla_id,
                'sla_name' => $returnsla->sla_name,
                'sla_days' => $returnsla->sla_days.'D '.$returnsla->sla_hours.'H '.$returnsla->sla_minutes.'M',
                'department_name' => $returnsla->department_name); //Here this SLA is assign to department X and Y, i want department_name = X, y
        }
        echo json_encode($returnslajson);
    }
}
```

I had added few comments at each line,

When SLA added i get only 1 department at output,

```
department_name: "X"
sla_days: "1D 1H 1M"
sla_id: "38"
sla_name: "qweqweq"
```

How can i get both department_name as X, Y

Below is output of array,$this->model_admin->getaddedsla($lastentry->sla_id)

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [sla_id] => 38 [sla_name] => qweqweq [sla_days] => 1 [sla_hours] => 1 [sla_minutes] => 1 [department_id] => 20 [department_name] => X ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [sla_id] => 38 [sla_name] => qweqweq [sla_days] => 1 [sla_hours] => 1 [sla_minutes] => 1  [department_id] => 21 [department_name] => Y ) )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: @sgtBOSE, i want my json output - department_name: "X,Y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with -

```
    //Now getadded SLA with join of department
    $department_name = $name = $days = $id = array();
    foreach($this->model_admin->getaddedsla($lastentry->sla_id) as $returnsla) {
        $name[] = $returnsla->sla_name;
        $id[] = $returnsla->sla_id;
        $days[] = $returnsla->sla_days.'D '.$returnsla->sla_hours.'H '.$returnsla->sla_minutes.'M';
        $department_name[] = $returnsla->department_name;
    }
    $returnslajson['department_name'] = implode(',', $department_name);
    $returnslajson['sla_id'] = implode(',', $id);
    $returnslajson['sla_name'] = implode(',', $name);
    $returnslajson['sla_days'] = implode(',', $days);
    echo json_encode($returnslajson);
```

Comment: i need sla_days: "1D 1H 1M"
sla_id: "38"
sla_name: "qweqweq" as well, i assume above one will echo only X,Y